# Kentor AuthServices with ADFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, adfs, adfs2.0, kentor-authservices

Can anybody let me know the possibility/steps to use Kentor Authservices with customer ADFS ?

So far we have successfully implemented Kentor library to integrate with customers' Okta setups (Okta as the IdP). We have got another customer requiring their employees to login on our site using its ADFS credentials.

For test purpose, I added another IdP node in the web.config setting login.microsoft.com as "signOnUrl" to post SAML login request, and expected to redirect back to our portal after authentication. But it presented with Microsoft apps options page and stayed there. What should be "entityId" ? How to set "ReturnUrl" etc are blank area for me as of now.

I need to know what direction I should move to enable SSO using customers' adfs with Kentor.

Answer (score 0):

On the ADFS side you can import the AuthServices metadata. It would be on:

https:/xxx/AuthServices/ address.

On the Kentor side, use the ADFS metadata:

https://my-adfs/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

The entityID, endpoints etc. are all there.

Comment: Thanks @nzpcmad for the direction. As u said ADFS side to import AuthServices metadata - but here I dont have any control on clients ADFS.

Comment: At max they can give their adfs user login page url. Do I need to tell them explicitly to import AuthServices metadata ? Also, can you please tell - how to use ADFS metadata on Kentor side ?

Comment: Use OWIN - http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/01/owin-adpnet-mvc-application-with.html. Yes, they must import the metadata as an ADFS RP.